# Como Atribuir uma Frase a uma linha de uma matriz de chars?

Tags: c, string, matriz

Quero modificar frases padrão de um jogo teórico. Por exemplo, o jogo tem a frase "Escolha um comando" e, sobre um estado determinado, gostaria de trocar todas as letras "o" e "a" por um @.

Para isso, pensei em implementar uma matriz de caracteres,

falas[100][500], que pode armazenar 100 frases de 500 caracteres.

Quero atribuír à falas[1] "Escolha uma ação", falas[2] "Você não pode ir ai", etc.

E, para fazer o que quero fazer, dado que o jogador está em tal estado, usaria sscanf em frase[x][] e percorreria toda a frase[x][i], com i indo de 0 à strlen frase[x].

Entretanto, não estou conseguindo nem atribuir e não sei como imprimir estas frases.

O primeiro problema é não saber como incluir o '\0' ao final de uma string digitada dentro do programa. Ao mesmo tempo, o %s deveria funcionar até achar o primeiro \0 no lixo de memória, e está imprimindo apenas um caractere aleatório no programa abaixo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){

   char falas [100][500];

   falas[1][0] =  "Seja bem vindo ao meu jogo";

   printf("%s", falas[1]);

}
```

Comment: Bom, aí complica um pouco porque tem várias coisas que não está conseguindo fazer, aí teremos que fazer todo o código para você, seria melhor enfrentar um problema por vez.

Comment: Apenas como atribuir strings a linhas de uma matriz de caracteres já ajudaria muito.

Comment: Quantas frases terão?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode atribuir usando *strcpy* que está no include *cstring*. Dessa forma o código que você colocou de exemplo deveria ser assim:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cstring>

int main() {

    char falas[100][500];

    strcpy(falas[0], "Seja bem vindo ao meu jogo");

    printf("%s", falas);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!